# HOw to Split a string containg "" in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string like this `adas:asd":"asd:asdas:dasd":"ad33q3sd:asd`
I want to split it like

```
Dim splited() As String
splited = Split(input,"":"")
```

but its not working i tried adding \ but same

```
 splited = Split(input,"\":\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Split should look like this:

```
splited = Split(input, """:""")
```

The first and last `"` define the string. The `""` escapes each `"`

This `"\":\""` is the C# notation

Answer (score 0):

The other method works well, this is just a variation. vba has a function called `chr(ascii_value)`, you supply the ascii value and chr returns the corresponding character. In this case a quote is ascii 34

```
splited = Split(input, chr(34) & "." & chr(34))
```

we've basically concatenated (`&`) our quotes with the period. using `chr()` for all your characters may be a bit silly and hard to read, but for quotes I think it's well used